# Formatting strings in a mutiline TextBox

Tags: .net, string, vb.net, string-formatting

I would like to add 3 strings to a multiline `TextBox` in this format:

```
  str1:    3000
 srr22:   23044
str333:  222222
```

I need to align these strings in the `TextBox` to the right.

I have tried this code:

```
Dim s1 As String = " str1: "
Dim n1 As Integer = 3000

Dim s3 As String=vbCrLf & String.Format("{0,15}", s1) & String.Format(" {0:d6}", n1)
txtKopfring.Text = s3
s1 = "str22: "
n1 = 23044

s3 = s3 & vbCrLf & String.Format("{0,15}", s1) & String.Format("{0:d6}", n1)
txtKopfring.Text = s3

s1 = "str333: "
n1 = 222222

s3 = s3 & vbCrLf & String.Format("{0,15}", s1) & String.Format("{0:d6}", n1)
txtKopfring.Text = s3
```

The output however was not as expected, could you provide hints to get the output correct?

Comment: Do you need to align only n1 ?

Comment: the output i need is written at the begenning, i need str1, str22, str333 to be aligned to the right, and also the numbers to be alligned to the right

Comment: Do you must use a textBox ?

Comment: i must not use text box, but it was exist from previous work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, change the font to a [fixed-width](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) font. I chose **Courier New**.

Now for this to work you need to know what the max length is of your numbers. In your example this is *222222* which has a length of **6**.

To achieve this what I did was add the numbers to a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim numbers As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
numbers.Add("str1: ", 3000)
numbers.Add("str22: ", 23044)
numbers.Add("str333: ", 222222)
```

I then found the max length of the `.Values` collection to work out which number had the largest length, padding out the numbers using the `maxLength`:

```
Dim maxLength As Integer = numbers.Values.Max.ToString.Length
```

The next job was to loop through the `Dictionary` and add the values to a [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
'Import System.Text
Dim sb As New StringBuilder

For Each number As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In numbers
    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0,15}", number.Key) & String.Format("{0:d6}", number.Value.ToString.PadLeft(maxLength)))
Next
```

> To use a `StringBuilder` you will have to import `System.Text`.

Lastly:

```
txtKopfring.Text = sb.ToString()
```

This gives me the following output:

[image]

If you didn't want to follow my logic, to achieve what you are after in your code, you can change:

```
String.Format(" {0:d6}", n1)
```

To:

```
String.Format("{0:d6}", n1.ToString.PadLeft(6))
```

> Note the 6 is hardcoded and not recommended as other values may come into play which could be longer in length and will throw the formatting out.

Also I have copied your code directly from your question and noticed a slight issue.

This `String.Format(" {0:d6}", n1)` has a space in the first argument and that will be potrayed in your formatting. Remove the space like such `String.Format("{0:d6}", n1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do it by a function that already exists in .NET?

```
txtKopfring.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use a textBox, you could use a datagridview.
Insert a datagridview in your form and name it dtgv.

Then, insert the following code :

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' Set columns properties
    initialisation_dtgv()

    With dtgv
        ' Set 3 rows.
        .RowCount = 3

        ' Set values for your cells
        .Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = "str1"
        .Rows(0).Cells(1).Value = 3000

        .Rows(1).Cells(0).Value = "srr22:"
        .Rows(1).Cells(1).Value = 23044

        .Rows(2).Cells(0).Value = "str333:"
        .Rows(2).Cells(1).Value = 222222
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub initialisation_dtgv()
    With dtgv
        Dim cols1 As New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        cols1.Name = "STR"
        cols1.HeaderText = "STR"
        cols1.ToolTipText = "STR"
        cols1.Width = 50
        cols1.Visible = True
        cols1.DisplayIndex = 1
        cols1.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
        ' Set the alignment of your column
        cols1.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
        .Columns.Add(cols1)

        Dim coln1 As New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        coln1.Name = "NUMBER"
        coln1.HeaderText = "NUMBER"
        coln1.ToolTipText = "NUMBER"
        coln1.Width = 60
        coln1.Visible = True
        coln1.DisplayIndex = 2
        ' Set the alignment of your column
        coln1.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
        coln1.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
        .Columns.Add(coln1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but datagrid view need more space on the form, and actually i dont have the required space, becuase i have to show more that 20 textbox on the form, i would go rather for gruoup

Comment: @waleedalmukawi, Would a datagridview with more rows be ok ? And by the way, you can change it's appearence if you need more space ;)